# Can't send ajax request

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've got this code:

```
$('#clicker_continue').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'includes/functions/register_user.php',
        data: {
            'username':dat_usr,
            'email':dat_email,
            'password':dat_pas,
            'question':dat_que,
            'answer':dat_ans,
            'ip':data.ip
        },  
        dataType:'html',
        succes:function(response){
            $('#main_wrapper').append(response);
        }
    });
```

When watching the Network Monitor and clicking on `#clicker_continue`, I don't see ajax requesting `register_user.php`. What is wrong here?

Comment: Whats the error? What happens when you click on clicker_continue?

Comment: Are there any errors? Try putting a `console.log()` statement at the top of the click handler to make sure it's at least getting to that point.

Comment: If you're not seeing an ajax request, the handler isn't being invoked. Most likely you're either binding to the element before it exists, or there are duplicate id's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First mistake is that you have a syntax error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. `})` is missing. This is probably your mistake that stops the request from being made.

Second one is that you have a typo: `succes` instead of `success` - this would not stop the request from being made but will not detect the response.

```
$('#clicker_continue').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'includes/functions/register_user.php',
        data: {
            'username':dat_usr,
            'email':dat_email,
            'password':dat_pas,
            'question':dat_que,
            'answer':dat_ans,
            'ip':data.ip
        },  
        dataType:'html',
        success:function(response){
            $('#main_wrapper').append(response);
        }
    });
}); // <<< You missed this
```

Answer (score 1):

Spelling mistake in your `$.ajax` call. You forget the extra `s` on the end of `success:`

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
     url: 'includes/functions/register_user.php',
     data: {'username':dat_usr, 'email':dat_email, 'password':dat_pas, 'question':dat_que, 'answer':dat_ans  ,'ip':data.ip},
     dataType:'html',
     success:function(response){
         $('#main_wrapper').append(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: How would that prevent the request from being made?

Comment: It may not but it's not correct code. The problem may stem from the PHP side - which we can't see.